# MySQL-Trigger Creation

Tags: mysql, triggers

am just trying to create one update trigger.Here is the code..

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_User_update 
 BEFORE UPDATE ON User
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO User_index
    SET action = 'update',
    firstName = OLD.firstName,
    email = OLD.email,
    changedat = NOW()
END 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For this code i got a error like this..

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 10

How can i solve this.. Please help me..

Comment: Missed a `;` after `changedat = NOW()`

Comment: i solve this.. Thanks for rply..